# Skrollr Parallax is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My home page is working on browser but not on mobile. I have use parallax here.

Can anyone help me out what may be the issue in it? Here is the HTML Code:

```
    <article id="banner" class="banner">
<span id="ipad" data-145="transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-700="transform:translate(0px,400px);"></span>
<span id="flower_big" data-145="transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-700="transform:translate(0px,400px);"></span>
<span id="flower_small" data-145="transform:translate(0px,0px);" data-700="transform:translate(0px,400px);"></span>
<span id="bloom" data-145="margin-top: 224px;" data-700="margin-top: 624px;"></span>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var s = skrollr.init();
</script>
```

Comment: I simply added an id="skrollr-body" to my body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Set a height on the division skrollr-body:

```
#skrollr-body {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```